# Под `system partition` в Windows10 понимается весь локальный диск на который установлен Windows (включая Program Files, Desktop и тд)?

Tags: windows

Контекст вопроса такой:

> VeraCrypt can on-the-fly encrypt a **system partition** or entire system
>   drive, i.e. a partition or drive where Windows is installed and from
>   which it boots. [source](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/System%20Encryption.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows 10 разделяет Reserved Partition, где она хранит BOOT файлы, и System Partition, где находятся системные папки (фактически, диск C:, хотя можно попытаться поставить систему и без именования букв).

Comment: Отлично. Спасибо. А под `entire system drive` они видимо физический диск имели ввиду?

Comment: @hipster Да, System Drive = диск, где находится System Partition Ж:)